# LSTM : ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type int)

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, lstm, sequential

I want to build a model that can suggest to the user the best HS Code of the good that will shipment by allowing to user enter a description for that good.

I am trying to build a neural network with LSTM layer to learn the data

### but it led to an error, so i need to want the reason of the error and how i can solve it.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import string

#######################################
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

#######################################
path = "/content/drive/MyDrive/data/dataset1.xlsx"
data = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(path))


def remove_punct(text):
    text  = "".join([char for char in text if char not in string.punctuation])
    text = re.sub('[0-9]+', '', text)
    text = re.sub("\n", '', text)
    # Remove extra spaces
    text = re.sub('\s+', ' ', text).strip()


    return text

data['Description_pun'] = data.iloc[:,0].apply(lambda x: remove_punct(x))
data.head(10)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZCB8Q.png)
####
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Embedding, LSTM, Dense
# Perform NLP on the text column
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(data.iloc[:,2])
word_index = tokenizer.word_index

sequences = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(data.iloc[:,2])
padded_sequences = pad_sequences(sequences)

# Prepare training data (80% of the dataset)
train_size = int(0.8 * len(data))
train_data = padded_sequences[:train_size]
train_labels = data.iloc[:10][:train_size]

# Prepare test data (20% of the dataset)
test_data = padded_sequences[train_size:]
test_labels = data.iloc[:,1][train_size:]

# Build LSTM model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(len(word_index) + 1, 100))  # Adjust embedding dimensions as needed
model.add(LSTM(100))  # Adjust LSTM units as needed
model.add(Dense(len(set(data.iloc[:,1])), activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=10)

# Make predictions based on user input
user_input = input('Enter the description of a good: ')
user_sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([user_input])
user_padded_sequence = pad_sequences(user_sequence, maxlen=len(train_data[0]))

predictions = model.predict(user_padded_sequence)
predicted_hscodes = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)

# Get the corresponding HSCodes and their probabilities
hscodes = list(set(data.iloc[:,0]))
probabilities = predictions[0]

results = []
for i in range(len(hscodes)):
    results.append((hscodes[i], probabilities[i]))

# Sort the results by probability in descending order
results.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

# Print the predicted HSCodes and their probabilities
for result in results:
    print(f'HSCODE: {result[0]}, Probability: {result[1]}')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4sEk.png)

I need to solve the problem and if know if builded model is good to the given problem

Comment: What are the shapes of your train_data and train_labels?